# Multiple IIS websites in multiple Docker containers with SNI

Tags: docker, iis, windows-server-2019

I'm migrating 10 sites hosted in the same server to to Docker. The idea is to continue having 1 single server but with 10 containers instead of 10 websites hosted in the host/main Windows and 10 sites configured in IIS.

The problem is that some of the websites use HTTPS on the same IP and port and use SNI (I believe that's what's being used even if 'Required' is not checked).

For example:

```
IP: 1.2.3.4, Port: 443, Host: aaa.com  >> Site 1
IP: 1.2.3.4, Port: 443, Host: bbb.com  >> Site 2
```

If I split those 2 sites in 2 containers, I won't be able to use SNI anymore right? If I understand correctly, the solution in the Linux world would be to create another container with nginx, varnish or apache. But how can I achieve this in Windows containers?

There are also other websites with other IPs and other ports (80 for plain HTTP), but I believe those are not a problem if I solve the issue mentioned above.

Comment: This is called virtual hosting. It sounds like IIS is currently configured as a reverse proxy. You can setup NGINX in Windows as well to be a reverse proxy. If you use docker swarm, you can put all of your sites in a docker stack and only bind the NGINX ports to the host. You would just manage traffic to each site by using the host name in the nginx.conf file. NGINX can even handle each SSL cert separately for each domain.

Comment: Thank you! From what I've read, Nginx in Windows is in Beta and only a "proof-of-concept". Not sure a good option for production. Any other way to configure it?

Comment: If you're stuck with IIS, maybe this article will help. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps/